# How to get a SpatRaster of indices of the nearest NA cell in R terra?

Tags: r, distance, raster, terra

From a digital elevation model, I'm trying to generate a raster of the difference in elevation between a water stream and its surroundings. That would be easy if the water stream was flat, but it is not.
Given a raster where the cells containing the stream are NA, the terra::distance() function can output a raster of the distance from each cell to the nearest NA cell.

Is there some similar function which could output a raster of the index of the nearest NA cell instead ?
Or even better for my use case, that would take in input two exactly overlapping rasters, one being the mask with NA values where the stream lies, and the other the DEM, and output a raster of either the elevation of the nearest NA cell ?

I have spent some time looking for such a function in the terra documentation without success. Can you think of a way to achieve the same thing without modifying terra ?
If there is no easy way to do it, I'll try sampling my stream with points, create a Voronoi diagram, assign each Voronoi polygon the elevation of its corresponding point, and rasterize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not well defined as there can be multiple nearest cells, but here are two approaches that you might follow.

Example data

```
library(terra)
elv <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
riv <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))[12] |> as.lines()
riv$val <- NA
elv <- rasterize(riv, elv, "val", update=TRUE)
```

You can compute the focal mean for the NA cells

```
felv <- focal(elv, 3, mean, na.policy="only")
```

Alternatively, you can find the values for adjacent cells

```
e <- extract(elv, riv, cell=TRUE)
a <- adjacent(elv, e$cell)
a <- cbind(a, extract(elv, a[,2])) |> na.omit()
b <- aggregate(a[, "elevation", drop=F], a[,"from", drop=FALSE], mean)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for pointing out that the problem is not well-defined.